# Get a new column with total count of all values between a specific range in a group_by df

Tags: python, pandas

An existing dataframe that was grouped by "u_id"

```
u_id  u_name   u_points   
   1      AA         12   
   1      AA         8    
   1      AA         5    
   2      BC         15   
   2      BC         9    
   2      BC         10   
   2      BC         6    
   2      BC         8
```

needs to have a new column that records a count of total "u_points" between a range (say 7-12, 7 inclusive, 12 exclusive) into every row. So the new dataframe would look like so:

```
u_id  u_name   u_points     u_range_(7-12)
   1      AA         12                  1 
   1      AA         8                   1
   1      AA         5                   1
   2      BC         15                  3
   2      BC         9                   3
   2      BC         10                  3
   2      BC         6                   3
   2      BC         8                   3
```

I tried using count() but I could get a series with only those index values but I need output in all rows. Also tried transform but it didn't work with condition "between".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for `>=` and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` by mask by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `<`, convert to numbers by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new column filled by aggregate values:

```
m = df['u_points'].ge(7) & df['u_points'].lt(12)

df['u_range_(7-12)'] = m.view('i1').groupby(df['u_name']).transform('sum')
#alternative
#df['u_range_(7-12)'] = m.astype('int').groupby(df['u_name']).transform('sum')
print (df)
   u_id u_name  u_points  u_range_(7-12)
0     1     AA        12               1
1     1     AA         8               1
2     1     AA         5               1
3     2     BC        15               3
4     2     BC         9               3
5     2     BC        10               3
6     2     BC         6               3
7     2     BC         8               3
```

Similar idea with appended new column:

```
m = df['u_points'].ge(7) & df['u_points'].lt(12)

df['u_range_(7-12)'] = df.assign(m = m.astype('int')).groupby('u_name')['m'].transform('sum')
print (df)
   u_id u_name  u_points  u_range_(7-12)
0     1     AA        12               1
1     1     AA         8               1
2     1     AA         5               1
3     2     BC        15               3
4     2     BC         9               3
5     2     BC        10               3
6     2     BC         6               3
7     2     BC         8               3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.merge(df[df['u_points'].between(7,12-1)].groupby('u_id').size().to_frame(name='u_range_(7-12)').reset_index(),
         on='u_id')
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a 'low effort way' to achieve the same result

```
df["u_range_(7-12)"] = pd.Series(np.where(df.u_points.between(7,12-1).values, 1,0)).groupby(df2['u_id']).transform('sum')
```

As I am new to Pandas, personally I find this preferable as it uses 'familiar' operations than the other well written answers.